# I am working on my react application, updated all dependencies but still getting this error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: navbar@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.2.0 || ^17.0.0" from react-modal-video@1.2.8
npm ERR! node_modules/react-modal-video
npm ERR!   react-modal-video@"^1.2.8" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\SajjadAli\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.     

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\SajjadAli\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-05-26T10_24_55_932Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Evidently `react-modal-video` doesn't yet officially support React 18. You'll either need to downgrade React, wait for the library to be updated or use one of the options _in the error message_ to suppress this.

Comment: as this line says `Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps` . Try using `npm i react-modal-video --legacy-peer-deps`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like react-modal-video requires a peer dependency of React 16 or 17, but you are using React 18.